# Why do ExecuteSQLRecord and CSVRecordSetWriter updated the time zone of datetime values?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to NiFi. I hope someone here can advise me about my problem with time zone. I have these processors:

ListDatabaseTables -> GenerateTableFetch -> ExecuteSQLRecord (writing to csv file by CSVRecordWriter) -> ... ... PutSQL (loading csv file to MySQL using Load Data command)

The source DB is Oracle. CSVRecordWriter has the following properties:

```
Schema Write Strategy -> Do Not Write Schema
Schema Access Strategy -> Inherit Record Schema
Schema Name -> ${schema.name}
Schema Text -> ${avro.schema}
Date Format -> yyyy-MM-dd
Time Format -> HH:mm:ss
Timestamp Format -> yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

My source DB and the target DB are both in US east time zone. However, I noticed that the output of ExecuteSQLRecord having time values converted to UTC (added to 5 hours). That results in the wrong time values in the target DB. There may be some ways to convert each date/time column individually, but that will require a huge amount of development effort.

Is there a way to handle this issue properly at global level, or at least at table level? Please note that Time Format needs to be acceptable to MySQL Load Data.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

NiFi works with absolute time values (UTC-based), only when the values need to be represented in text format (CSV, JSON, XML, etc.) is the value converted to a String timestamp and it uses ISO 8601 formatting, meaning the timezone (if not UTC) shows up in the String.

However MySQL expects all timestamps (literals and values) in the database's host machine timezone (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html)) and does not accept timezone values ([in a literal for example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168345/gmt-timezone-in-mysql-timestamp-literal-value)). Technically you need to change the time value by treating the UTC value as if it were really in the target timezone (subtract 5 hours from the value, e.g.).

I think you'd need to [set the timezone of the session](https://smarttechways.com/2018/11/02/check-and-set-the-database-and-session-time-zone-in-oracle/) for the source DB using the `SQL Pre-Query` property of ExecuteSQLRecord. If that has the effect of having the timestamp values come out looking like they're in the target DB timezone, then MySQL should take care of the rest. If that doesn't work, you may need to manually subtract 5 hours from the timestamp values with UpdateRecord or a scripting processor.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that NiFi text based writers implicitly convert all db dates (oracle in our case) to UTC. But there seems to be a bug with the conversion to UTC, some dates are getting converted with daylight saving hours and some without the daylight savings. For example, for the the same source table (based in Australia/Sydney tz) with dates 31/Dec/99 13:00:00 and 30/Apr/19 14:00:00, the csv values in the flowfiles are 31/Dec/99 02:00:00 and 30/Apr/19 04:00:00 respectively, which is a difference of +11:00 and +10:00 hours. UTC conversion is inconsistent within the same flowfile.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mat.
I tried setting session timezone for Oracle. It didn't work.

I figured out a workaround by using the following query to generate another query to be executed by the next step. This query converts Oracle date values to the preferred strings at the global level so it save the development effort at column level or table level.

SELECT
LISTAGG(
CASE WHEN COLUMN_ID =1 THEN 'SELECT ' || CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('DATE','TIMESTAMP') THEN 'TO_CHAR(' || COLUMN_NAME || ',''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'') AS ' || COLUMN_NAME
ELSE COLUMN_NAME END
ELSE CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('DATE','TIMESTAMP') THEN 'TO_CHAR(' || COLUMN_NAME || ',''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'') AS ' || COLUMN_NAME
ELSE COLUMN_NAME END
END
,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_ID)
|| ' FROM ' || '${db.table.name}' AS MY_RECORD
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = '${db.table.name}'
;